# function ipress in behat is not works

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1, behat

i have make test with behat in symfony but is not working.

this is my feature:

```
Feature: dossiertest
```

@javascript

Scenario: List 2 files in a directory

```
Given I am on the homepage
Then I should see "hello"
When I go to "/ajoutermed"
Then I should see "ajouter"
And I wait 2 seconds
And I fill in "test_medbundle_med_section" with "tes nom"
And I fill in "test_medbundle_med_info" with "tes nom"
And I press "Ajouter Med"
Then I should see "ajouter"
```

this is AjouterContext.php:

```
<?php

namespace test\MedBundle\Behat\Context;

use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Behat\Context\BehatContext;
use Behat\Behat\Exception\PendingException;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;
use test\MedBundle\Entity\Apps;
use test\MedBundle\Entity\Product;

/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class AjouterContext extends MinkContext
{


    /**
     * @When I press :arg1
     */
    public function iPress($arg1)
    {
       self::$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector($arg1))->click();


            //$element = $page->find('css',"input[value='$arg1']");
    }
   

     /**
     * @Then I wait :arg1 seconds
     */
    public function iWaitSeconds($arg1)
    {
        $this->getSession()->wait($arg1 * 1000);
    }


}
```

behat.yml:

```
default:
    suites:
        default:
            bundle: MedBundle
            contexts:
                - test\MedBundle\Behat\Context\FeatureContext
                - test\MedBundle\Behat\Context\AjouterContext
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: http://localhost/test/web/app_dev.php
            goutte: ~
            javascript_session: selenium2
            selenium2:
                wd_host: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
            sessions:
                default:
                    symfony2: ~
```

and this is my problem when i launche test:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t67lF.png)

help me please and thank you

Comment: You should use page objects and maybe have a base page object that extents `Page` where you can override some methods if you need too and  add few new common ones. Make sure you have a good structure before you start else you will add unnecessary complexity and it will be harder to debug. Please take a look here http://behat-page-object-extension.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

regarding your error message, there is an ambigous "@When I press" action. If you change your function iPress by

```
/**
* @When I click on input :arg1
*/
public function iClickOnInput($arg1)
{
    self::$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector($arg1))->click();
    //$element = $page->find('css',"input[value='$arg1']");
}
```

It should work.

Comment: with this feature :   When I click on input "Ajouter Med", and this function : /**
* @When I click on input :arg1
*/
public function iClickOnInput($arg1)
{
    self::$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector($arg1))->click();
    //$element = $page->find('css',"input[value='$arg1']");
}
i have this error:
http://imgur.com/a/Swv89

Comment: with this function : /**
     * @When I click on :arg1
     */
    public function iClickOn2($arg1)
    {
         $element = $this->getSession()->getPage()->findById($arg1);
      if (null === $element) {var_dump('Could not evaluate element with ID: "%s"', $arg1);
      }$element->click();} 
i have this error: http://imgur.com/a/G1d5F
id 'test_medbundle_med_submit' exists in input submit Ajouter Med but i have this error

Answer (score 0):

If is a button element and it has `Ajouter Med` as one of the following id|name|title|alt|value then it should work with `I press "Ajouter Med"`

If this is a link then you should use `I follow "Ajouter Med"`

Make sure you try to search the appropriate method to use, try using an IDE editor with autocomplete for Behat/Gherkin steps and for php methods.

Avoid writing your own custom base methods/steps, do this only if you have no alternative, you might end with 2-3 steps that are doing the same thing.

Comment: Ajouter Med is a input submit

Comment: Then the default `I press` from Mink should work if you are using one of the attributes `id|name|title|alt|value`.